# Consolidate rows in report

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

If a row has the same ID as the last one, I want to combine them - summing up the `cubicFt` and `Savings`. `$perFt` divides the savings by the `cubicFt`, so it wouldn't be summed, simply dividing the new results.  I also want the Descriptions to be concatenated, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Group based on ID (or whatever the leftmost column is). Then suppress the Details section and the Group Header. Instead, you'll be putting all the fields you want to display in the Group Footer. From there it's simple:

1. Create a Summary or Running Total for both `cubicFt` and `Savings`.
2. Reconfigure your `$PerFt` to use the summary/running total fields you made in step 1.
3. Combine the Descriptions by creating a shared string variable `Descriptions`. Whenever the  group changes, reset it with `Descriptions = ""`. Whenever the group *doesn't* change, add the description string to your variable. Something like:

   ```
   Descriptions = Descriptions & " ; " & {yourtable.Description}
   ```

Then create a final formula `ShowDescription` in the Group Footer to display the results with `RIGHT(Descriptions, LEN(Descriptions)-2)`

Comment: For another report, its similar data, but with another field, Completion Date, that contains a date.  I want to consolidate rows with the same DSMI but only if they also share the same completion date.  Can I do this?

Comment: Certainly - if I understand you correctly you want to nest groups. Add a completion date grouping to the chain and it will separate those by date.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do grouping, either by modifying the SELECT statement or the stored query that generates the data, or within Crystal Reports. I'm literally 20 years out of date on Crystal Reports, although I have used similar software, so this will have to be tweaked.

For the first solution, all you need is a concatenation aggregation function for the string field. Your DB may or may not have one built in, so you may need to add it.

```
SELECT Building, ID, 
  SUM(cubicFt), SUM(savings),
  SUM(savings)/SUM(cubicFt) AS [$perft], 
  LEFT(STRING_AGG(description, ';'), -1) -- drop extra ; at end
GROUP BY Building, ID;
```

However, you should be able to do the same *within* Crystal by setting this up as a subtotal group (not sure if you have to do user definitions for the string aggregation), *and then hiding the detail section.*